# "Get-AdComputer -filter" doesnt return anything when looking for Vista Clients

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-management

Why does `Get-Computers -OperatingSystem "Windows VistaT Business"` not return anything? It works perfectly for all the other OS types.

```
Function Get-Computers
{
    Param($OperatingSystem)

    Get-AdComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -eq ${OperatingSystem}' -SearchBase "OU=Departement,DC=contoso,DC=com"
}

#Get-Computers -OperatingSystem "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard"
#Get-Computers -OperatingSystem "Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard"
#Get-Computers -OperatingSystem "Windows 7 Professional"
Get-Computers -OperatingSystem "Windows VistaT Business"
```

I definitly do have Vista clients and the string to look for is `Windows VistaT Business`.

```
PS C:\> (get-adcomputer ClientA -Properties *).OperatingSystem
Windows 7 Professional
PS C:\> (get-adcomputer ClientB -Properties *).OperatingSystem
Windows VistaT Business
```

Comment: Why the down vote? My question is specific and clear

Comment: Does the computer live in your searchbase?  Could the computer object be in another OU than what you're searching?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That `T` in "VistaT" is no T at all - it represents a trademark symbol: ™ (U+2122 or #8482 in Unicode)

Try this:

```
Get-Computers -OperatingSystem $("Windows Vista" + [char]8482 + " Business")
```

Why Microsoft chose to abuse the ability to store unicode symbols in string value attributes in this way is beyond me.

---

Here is how I found out:

(When you cast a .NET `char` to an integer, you'll get the byte value for ASCII chars, or a 2-byte codepoint for unicode characters)

```
$osString = (Get-ADComputer [VistaComputerName] -Properties operatingSystem).operatingSystem

foreach($c in $osString.ToCharArray())
{
    Write-Host $("$c: " + "$([int]$c)")
}
```

At this point, my output consisted of all ASCII chars (all integers a single byte), except for the `T`:

```
W: 87
i: 105
n: 110
d: 100
o: 111
w: 119
s: 115
 : 32
V: 86
i: 105
s: 115
t: 116
a: 97
T: 8482
 : 32
B: 66
u: 117
s: 115
i: 105
n: 110
e: 101
s: 115
s: 115
```

Comment: Microsoft's relationship with Unicode is such a sordid tale.

Comment: I would never have figued that out by myself. Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer with how I actually found out